# Sorting two arrays with arrayadapter, files and files description

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, android-arrayadapter

I have 2 arrays of String[]:
String[] mFileList;
String[] mFileList_description;
This is my function that shows alert dialog with list of files description:

```
private void Load_file_list(){
Dialog dialog = null;
AlertDialog.Builder alertdg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
alertdg.setTitle("FILES");
alertdg.setTitle("Select file");

final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
final EditText filtr = new EditText(this); 
final ListView lista = new ListView(this); 

 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, mFileList_description);
 lista.setAdapter(adapter);
/////////
 filtr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // sort
        adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
 });
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.d("TEST","File id:"+arg2+" File name:"+mFileList[arg2]);
    }
   });
 /////////

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.addView(filtr); 
layout.addView(lista); 
alertdg.setView(layout); 
alertdg.show(); 
}
```

I have problem, when I sort my list of description, becouse setOnItemClickListener method return id of description that user click, but it isn't id in array mFileList (sometimes this id is from another file)
How to implement sort my files with desctiption ? I tired to done this in two-demensial array, but I think another way will be better...

Thanks, and sorry for my English... ;)

Answer (score 0):

First and for most, **you are following a bad pattern here**.

### Optimized Solution:

Instead of keeping 2 Arrays, I would suggest you to keep 1 `Array` or `ArrayList` of user-defined object type.

For example:

```
/**
Here `MyFileClass` is a clsss with attributes whatever you want to store for 
Files and also contains getter/setter methods **/

MyFileClass[] objFiles = new MyFileClass[4];
or
ArrayList<MyFileClass> listFileObjs = new ArrayList<MyFileClass>();
```

But Again I would suggest you to go with `ArrayList` because its easy to manage as compared to  `Array`.

Now, as you are having single `ArrayList<MyFileClass>` you can easily manage it by performing whatever operation you want.